# Plot 4 graphs in single page with each graph has multiple y axes using Plotly JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plotly, plotly.js

I want to plot 4 graphs in single page with each graph has multiple y axes in it using Plotly JS,Can Anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this reference from Plotly docs: [Plotly.js subplots](https://plotly.com/javascript/subplot-charts/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have seen this but I'm looking for multiple graphs(4*4 grid) with multiple y axes in each graph, In this example all graph is having single y axis